# How does Windows group font files?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, microsoft-word-2010

I've downloaded a font. The ZIP contains 3 files:

- my-font-regular.otf
- my-font-medium.otf
- my-font-demi.otf

I've clicked every file to view it and then clicked the Install button.
Now MS Word displays 3 new entries in the font drop down:

- My Font Regular
- My Font Medium
- My Font Demi

How do I make Windows and Word untderstand that it's the same font and display only one entry? For example Word doesn't show 4 entries (Bold, Bold Italic and so on) for Times New Roman.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot specify anywhere that it's the same font in different styles.
This has to be defined inside the font file itself by the creator of the font.

In short, the creator should have given all the fonts an identical Family Name, but different Style Names.
Evidently, he didn't.

The only solution is to edit the fonts and change their characteristics,
in effect creating your own versions of these fonts.
But that requires specialized knowledge about fonts.

Answer (score 0):

There are some more specific solutions using FontForge and TTFedit on this thread: [Change Font Family, Rename Font](https://superuser.com/questions/472102/change-font-family-rename-font)