# Change Font Family, Rename Font

Tags: fonts

How can I change a font's Family? I have 4 fonts belonging to the same family and I wish to separate them.

Also, I would also want to rename the Font itself.

A simple file name change is NOT enough.

I'm looking for a free tool to do this, but came out empty handed after Googling a bit. All Font "studios" demand money.

I should specify that I need to do this in the Operating System itself, so I need to modify the TTF/OTF/actual font file.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming...?

Comment: I need this for a Flash-player related issue. Besides, programmers know tools ::- ). Anyway, I realized that I might have posted this on SuperUser or somewhere else, but I just didn't know if that's a better place for this question. You decide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change a TTF font name?](https://superuser.com/questions/120593/how-do-you-change-a-ttf-font-name)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any special reason for changing the font details? (just curious...)

anyway i found this little tool: http://fontforge.org/ (Which is cross platform and open source!)

hope it helps :)

Comment: It's a long story :D. There are some issues regarding the way Adobe Flash returns me the Font Name so I need to rename them in order to achieve a certain task.

Comment: Thanks for this. Font Forge helped me to resolve a name conflict by changing the name of OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic from the accidentally named OpenSans-Italic.

Answer (score 8):

[TTFedit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ttfedit/) did the job for me. It has a much smaller footprint and was easier to use for me.

Just start ttfedit.jar, open a .ttf, select the "name" tab on the left side, edit the family names, subfamily names, etc. and save as a new .ttf.

In my case, I had to wipe Photoshop's font cache before my changed font got recognized.

Answer (score 3):

I know that is a bit older, but I found a method for `.otf` files:

1. Download FontForge
2. Edit the three names (>Element,>Fontinfo) and export it as a `.ttf` file.
3. Then grab this old Windows program: https://www.microsoft.com/typography/property/fpedit.htm
4. Open the created `.ttf` with `fpedit` and skip the steps (just click next till the program is ready)
5. Click on "Save as"
6. Be happy

Answer (score 2):

Just import your font file in the online [GlyphrStudio](https://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/) font editor, click on menu icon and go to `Font settings`, apply your desire changes and export the font.

Answer (score 1):

If you upload the font's file (with the new name) to the server you can use it after defining it as a font. For example:
If I want Arial to be called Ari, I can just change the file's name and upload it to my server. Then I will just write the following line in the css file:

```
@font-face{font-family:Ari; src:url('Ari.ttf');}
```

**font-family** is the name of the new font.

**src** is the file's address.

To use the new font write something like: H1{font-family:'Ari';}

As to the first part of your question, I don't understand what you mean. Please clarify.

Comment: I maybe should have specified that I need to do this with some fonts in my Windows installation.

Answer (score 1):

**fontname.py** allows to rename a font on the CLI, it depends on *fonttools*.

Git repo: https://github.com/chrissimpkins/fontname.py

**fonttools** could be installed with pip: `pip3 install fonttools`

Example for renaming a font title (new title will be: *Nerd Symbols 2048*):

`python fontname.py 'Nerd Symbols 2048' 'Symbols-2048-em Nerd Font Complete.ttf'`

Answer (score 0):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53427523/1107290) on StackOverflow:

> - Import your font file in the online [Glyphrstudio font editor](http://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/)
> - Click the hamburger icon on the top left
> - Select **font setting** and change title and meta data from there

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.